# QGIS - QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource - Filter input layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

In QGIS, I try to write a script for a custom toolbox. I'm using the processing framework logic and following [official documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Processing/QgsProcessingFeatureSource.html). I add an input vector layer, but I can't handle it has a [QgsVectorLayer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html).

For example when I wan't to apply a filter to the selected layer I have an error message:

> AttributeError: 'QgsProcessingFeatureSource' object has no attribute
> 'setSubsetString'

Here is an extract of my script:

```
class DissolveProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    ...

def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )    
        # Filter
        filter_value = '1'
        source.setSubsetString('"my_field"=\'%s\'' % filter_value)
```

How to handle `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource` as a vector layer has defined in `initAlgorithm` method ?

Comment: Use the [materialize()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureSource.html#ab95bcca99b1d5c082ca409da04e280b9) method to return an in-memory vector layer from the `QgsProcessingFeatureSource` object.

Comment: That's the good way. I used `new_layer = source.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(source.allFeatureIds()))`. After this I can do `new_layer.setSubsetString('"my_field"=\'%s\'' % filter_value)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new vector layer and copy what you need to it.
There's no point in modifying the input.

I recommend to check the plugin builder template https://github.com/g-sherman/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/blob/master/plugin_templates/processing_provider/template/module_name_algorithm.tmpl

(install 'plugin builder' plugin)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).